# How to make Mac application respond to command tilde key shortcut to switch windows

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

In most Mac applications it is possible to switch between the open windows of an application using the `cmd ~` key shortcut.
I want this in my app too, but I really don't see how to implement.

Most key shortcuts are implemented by adding a shortcut to one of the menu items. But for this one a menu item is not applicable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Keyboard preferences pane, under the Shortcuts pane, Command-` is a system-level keyboard shortcut in the Keyboard category (labeled "Move focus to next window").

Comment: Oh oops. I had a customer complaining that it didn't work in my app. So I went to search how to support it. But indeed it simply works, served by the system without writing a single line of code.